# How to read in the contents of a .rb file?

Tags: ruby, file-io

I can read any file with Ruby (v1.9.3-p125) but have trouble with the following commands:

```
IO.read("myself.rb")
File.open("myself.rb","rb")
```

When doing this on a "*.rb" file, it will return a blank string. If i rename the file "myself.rabit" it works.

How can I get around the apparent filtering of ruby source files?

Comment: Oops... I realized the .rb file was still open, after writing to it.. Closing the file before reading helps!

Comment: Also, myself was prolly a misnomer, it isn't actually the same file as the script's filename

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Ok, but really this question should be closed as "not constructive". The question asked depends on a problem that doesn't exist, as such the solution won't help any future users.

Comment: @meagar Not sure how it's "not constructive", there can (and is) an answer supported by "facts, references, or specific expertise". Perhaps "too localized". No matter.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Because the premis of the question is wrong. No valid answer can be given. It's like asking "Why doesn't 1 plus 2 equal 3?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such filtering, you're not encountering the bug you think you're encountering.

For instance, this works just fine as a complete Ruby program stored in a `.rb` file:

```
puts File.open(__FILE__).read
```

Comment: Marking as correct for the "wrong bug" pointer.... be sure to close files!

Answer (score 0):

You already got the correct answer: Use `__FILE__`.

There is also another possibility when you want to read your main file.

See the following code:

```
p DATA
p DATA.pos
p DATA.read

__END__
This is text after __END__
```

When you execute it, you get

```
#<File:test.rb>
50
"This is text after __END__"
```

`DATA` is a file handle, positioned after the end of the script (`__END__`) - in my example it is position 50.

I often use this `DATA` to store data in a kind of 'here-document'.

You could use this possibility for your use, just set the position to the file start.

```
DATA.pos= 0
puts DATA.read
```

Two restrictions:

- It works only with the main file, not with any file.
- `__END__` is obligatory.